# LinkedIn Scraper: How do I convert a list of company names into LinkedIn URLs?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I built a LinkedIn web scraper using Python, Selenium, and BeautifulSoup which takes in a company's Linkedin URL and outputs information about the company e.g its competitors.

The problem I have is that my input is a list of company names. Is there a way where I can convert this list of company names into a list of LinkedIn URLs that I can feed into the web scraper? Thank you.

Comment: I ran into this issue myself and found that the URLs between companies is not consistent enough to be able to just add the company name to www.linkedin.com/company/ 

I created a secondary scraper that would search the list of company names, and take the URL of the top search result using Selenium which worked with higher accuracy than trying to form the URL by guessing the structure.

Comment: so did your selenium scraper search each company name on google and then clicked on its linkedin?

Comment: Searched it within linkedin - I set up a similar one for googling but found it was less accurate. The only issue here is of course that for smaller companies it may be less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would work:

```
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/" + company_name
```

Lets say "https://www.linkedin.com/company/apple/"

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
companies = ['companyA','companyB','companyC']

['https://www.linkedin.com/company/'+c for c in companies]
```

Output:

```
['https://www.linkedin.com/company/companyA', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/companyB', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/companyC']
```

or iterate directly:

```
companies = ['companyA','companyB','companyC']

for company in companies:
    url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/'+company
    #perform a request
    #scrape what you need
```